# WASD movement with ncurses (Not sure why it doesnt work)

Tags: c, ncurses

I wanted to create a program with what i had just learned in ncurses. With it the user should be able to draw with a # in the screen using WASD. this is the code i did:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ncurses.h>

int main (void)
{
        initscr();
        noecho();
        int coord_x = 10;
        int coord_y = 10;
        char direccion;
        mvwprintw(stdscr,coord_y,coord_x,"#");
        while (1)
        {
                refresh();
                direccion = getchar();
                switch (direccion)
                {
                  case 'w':
                        coord_y -= 1;
                  case 's':
                        coord_y += 1;
                  case 'a':
                        coord_x -= 1;
                  case 'd':
                        coord_x += 1;
                  case 'q':
                        break;
                  default:
                        continue;
                }
                if (coord_x == -1 && coord_y == -1) { coord_y += 1;coord_x += 1;}
                mvwprintw(stdscr,coord_y,coord_x,"#");
                if (direccion == 'q') {break;}
        }
        endwin();
        return 0;
}
```

But i am not really sure why does the # wont move neither up or left. I think the problem is in this part:

```
direccion = getchar();
                switch (direccion)
                {
                  case 'w':
                        coord_y -= 1;
                  case 's':
                        coord_y += 1;
                  case 'a':
                        coord_x -= 1;
                  case 'd':
                        coord_x += 1;
                  case 'q':
                        break;
                  default:
                        continue;
                }
```

But i am really not sure, do you know why it doesnt work?

EDIT: Thanks to everybody, now i realised im just dumb and forgot how to use a switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `break`s after each assignment in your switch statement:

```
switch (direccion) {
case 'w':
    coord_y -= 1;
    break; /* <-- here */
case 's':
    coord_y += 1;
    break; /* <-- here */
case 'a':
    coord_x -= 1;
    break; /* <-- here */
case 'd':
    coord_x += 1;
    break; /* <-- here */
case 'q':
    break;
default:
    continue;
}
```

The default behavior of the `case` is to "fall through" to the next one, so if you press `w` it is going to execute all of the `coord_x` and `coord_y` assignments, not just the one you intend.

Comment: As an aside, you should also call `curs_set(0);` to hide the cursor. Looks better that way.